# AEM - Multifield Add Item by default

Tags: adobe, aem

I am using multifield of type pathfield in my dialog. To add new path field, user has to click Add Item link.
Is it possible to display at least one path field in the dialog by default (without clicking Add Item)?

Comment: I don't know whether any of these two would work, but have you tried setting a default value for the multifield in the dialog.xml ([search for multifield here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html)), or creating an initial content for your component where you explicitly create an empty list of paths ([this doc page might help](http://labs.sixdimensions.com/blog/2014-07-08/using-the-cq-template/) )

Comment: thanks for looking into it. Both the ways will work as long as I provide some value. If I leave default value as blank then it will not automatically add pathfield widget by default

Comment: do you want to get an just empty field (so they dont have to click + ) or do you need a default value for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open first item of multifield on load of dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073857/how-to-open-first-item-of-multifield-on-load-of-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There was a similar question for which I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075636/1201244).

However, for future references, providing the answer here too.

You can listen to the `loadcontent` event fired by the Multifield after the content has been loaded and use the `addItem()` method.

```
<paths
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Select Paths"
    name="./paths"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        xtype="pathfield" />
    <listeners
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      loadcontent="function(field, record)
      {
       if(record.get('paths') == undefined)
       {
        field.addItem(); field.doLayout();
       }
      }" />
</paths>
```