# How to open first item of multifield on load of dialog?

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I need to open first item of multifield on dialog load. I looked at the API documentation of multifield but not able to find.

```
<promo
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="abcd"
                    hideLabel="false"
                    itemId="abcd"
                    name="./abcd"
                    xtype="[multifield]">
                    <fieldConfig
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        hideLabel="false"
                        layout="form"
                        name="./abcd"
                        title="abcd Item Info"
                        xtype="customPanel">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">

                        </items>
                    </fieldConfig>
                </promo>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: "I need to open first item of multifield on dialog load" -- What do you mean by "open" ? A screenshot of the requirement will be more helpful .

Comment: I dont need to click on add items. I need to display at least one path field in the dialog by default (without clicking Add Item) . Not able send you screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the `loadcontent` event fired by the [Multifield](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.MultiField) after the content has been loaded. If there was no content available initially, use the `addItem()` method to add an item and then redo the layout.

A sample configuration using multiple path field is shown below. You can adapt the same as per your requirements.

```
<promo
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="Select Paths"
    name="./paths"
    xtype="multifield">
    <fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        xtype="pathfield" />
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        loadcontent="function(field, record)
        {
           if(record.get('paths') == undefined)
          {
            field.addItem(); field.doLayout();
          }
        }" />
</promo>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. it is working fine. I have one more issue. i am having two radio buttons(multifield/dialogfieldset) in dialog. on selection of radio buttons i am showing/hiding multifield comp and dialogfield set. when i am on second radio button(dialogfield set) and multifield is hidden and clicking on 'ok' of dialog, the values in multifield are not persisting. it is again coming to default state. can you please suggest how to persist values of multifield if it is hidden.

Comment: I guess the issue you are mentioning is not specific to the solution that is provided here. Hence post it as a separate question so that people can look into it and answer. Updating queries in comments might not attract the best answer.

Comment: is it possible to do this in cq:dialog (Granite UI)?

Answer (score 2):

Improving the above provided solution, try to replace the loadcontent line with,

```
loadcontent="function(field, record) {if(field.getValue().length == 0) {field.addItem();} }"
```

Comment: This could better be a comment to already mentioned & approved answer.

Comment: @hB0 The authors reputation is to low to add a comment to a post.